# continuously changing numbers letter numbering by numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I want something like that below.

```
$number = request('number');

if ($number > 999) {
    $letter = 'A';
} elseif ($number > 1999) {
    $letter = 'B';
} elseif ($number > 2999) {
    $letter = 'c';
}
```

.
.
.

but it doesn't.
number and letter will change continuously..
for example if number 4500 then letter => E

Comment: You're only ever gonna get A (or nothing). 0-999 will be nothing, 1000+ will be A.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want if condition should auto increment letters. Continuously changing numbers
If my number is 5988, how many letters should it be?
this code below

```
$realNumber = $fooText . $fooYear. $letter. $number;
**like**
=> test2019G5988
=> nst2018C3544
```